# Add a mapview in Tab based app

Tags: android, google-maps, tabs, android-fragments, android-mapview

I have a tab based app and in on of the tabs you can navigate to the map screen like this:

`select a category > select a company > click on 'contact us' button`.

'Contact us' is the screen where I want to show the map. I read that a `Fragment` (Google map) cannot be added to a fragment below API 11 (Honeycomb). Do I have any alternative to Google

Maps API to achieve my target? Or is there a workaround? My minimum SDK is API 8 and target is 17.

Comment: This may help you take a look. http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new `Google Map API V2` with devices with lower SDK then 11 by using the `google-support-v4` library that delivers support of fragment to the older SDK's prior to Honeycomb.

So you don't need any workaround you can go ahead and use `Google Maps API V2`. Just remember to
make the needed referencing and use the `SupportMapFragment` and `FragmentActivity` objects.

You can get more information on how to integrate Google Maps API in your app by reading this blog post I wrote on this topic:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Comment: How will I add this MapFragment on my Fragment, so that I could perform operations such as place pins) on it?

Comment: I never performed this operation, for what I know as MapFragment is already a fragment and you want to place it another fragment, which means that you want fragment cascading which is allowed only from the last api.

Comment: So is there a workaround? (I aim to support API 8 and upwards)

Comment: then you can't use MapFragment, and should use SupportMapFragment and FragmentActivity instead of a simple Activity. why would you want to put inside a fragment. use the map fragment as a stand alone fragment.

Comment: It's a tab based app and the screen on which I need to show the map has some other details (address, phone no., etc) so I need to show a bit more things than just a map. What do you suggest? I tried subclassing `SupportMapFragment`, wasn't successful in the attempt though (with `getMap()` call).